# What is http-remoting Protocol

Tags: java, http, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I have set up an EJB on Wildfly and wrote a client to access it. With the protocol "http-remoting" it works fine.

Unfortunately, I am not sure about the functional details of http-remoting.

I guess this is a http-tunnel of the RMI protocol. But I can't find any suitable resources about this topic. So I am really unsure.

Does anybody know how http-remoting is working as a protocol?

Comment: It looks like remote EJB via HTTP: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072246/simple-spring-http-remoting-example.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a protocol implemented in [JBoss Remoting](http://jbossremoting.jboss.org/remoting-3.html). There is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jboss-remoting/jboss-remoting) for it as well.

Also depending on the version of WildFly you're using you may need to use `remote+http` or `remote+https`. The `http-remoting` protocol will still work, but is deprecated.

Comment: thank for your answer, do you know the differences between remote+http and http-remoting? are both http tunnels?

Comment: They are the same. `http-remoting` has been deprecated and `remote+http` should be used. It may depend on the version of WildFly you're using though. I don't recall which version `remote+http` came in on.

Comment: So this will not work with non-jboss containers? E.g. TomEE?

Comment: It will more than likely only work for JBoss/WildFly containers. It's really a protocol for JBoss Remoting which JBoss EAP and WildFly happen to use.

Answer (score 2):

From JBoss Redhat solutions site (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3259861)
remote: is the JBoss EAP 6 remoting protocol. It is not HTTP and cannot be used through a load balancer as it is designed to make a persistent connection to a host

http-remoting
http-remoting: / https-remoting: is the JBoss EAP 7.0+ remoting protocol that uses http-upgrade, it will connect via HTTP and then use http-upgrade and switch to the remoting protocol. Though it is HTTP, it cannot be used through a load balancer for load balancing, it is designed to make a persistent connection to the remote host and remain connected until the JVM is shut down or closed by the client.

remote+http
Works the same as http-remoting.

http
In JBoss EAP 7.2 this protocol can be used as an HTTP protocol that can be used through a load balancer as it does not use http-upgrade and it can be load balanced via an HTTP load balancer.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem very useful seeing as the question was already answered in 2017 and http-remoting has not massively changed since.